# Add items to ant's PATH without breaking stuff

Tags: java, linux, macos, unix, ant

In `ant`, how can I add to `PATH` without breaking stuff in `/usr/bin`?  I'm working directly from the Apache ant documentation for appding to `PATH` https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html (Examples section).

The documentation refers to `searchpath` which is described as follows:

> **`searchpath`**: When this attribute is `true`, then system path environment variables will be searched when resolving the location of the executable. since Ant 1.6.3

... but `searchpath` doesn't seem to help this particular problem either.

Take the following example `build.xml`:

```
<project name="Sample" default="init" basedir=".">
  <description>Testing PATH with exec</description>
  <target name="init">
    <exec executable="./test.sh">
      <env key="PATH" value="${env.PATH}:/foo"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

And the following shell script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello!"  # This works
uname          # If PATH is edited, shows "uname: command not found"
```

The output:

```
init:
     [exec] Hello!
     [exec] ./test.sh: line 3: uname: command not found
     [exec] Result: 127
```

... however if I comment out the `<env key="PATH" value="${env.PATH}:/foo"/>` it works fine.  How do you add to `PATH` without breaking stuff?

I'm testing with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.3 and Apache Ant 1.10.6 on MacOS 10.14.5 "Mojave".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.. Apache Ant documentation assumes somewhere in your code you've called the following:

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

Without this, `PATH` will be set to the literal string `${env.PATH}`, thus clobbering the `PATH` value.  This can be observed by echoing the value of `$PATH` in the shell script.

Their documentation has this in the examples, but it was missed in the above example causing the issue.

```
<project name="Sample" default="init" basedir=".">
  <description>Testing PATH with exec</description>
  <target name="init">
  <property environment="env"/><!-- THIS WAS MISSING -->
    <exec executable="./test.sh">
      <env key="PATH" value="${env.PATH}:/foo"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```